# Prime number recursive StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, recursion

I want to calculate prime numbers with a recursive function called `primzahlenRekursiv`, but I get a `StackOverflowException` in the function `istPrimzahl`, where I check if the current number is prime.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        primzahlenRekursiv(2);
    }

    static void primzahlenRekursiv(int primzahl) 
    {
        if (istPrimzahl(primzahl, 2)) { Console.Writeline(primzahl); }
        primzahlenRekursiv(primzahl + 1);
    }

    static bool istPrimzahl(int primzahl, int zahl) 
    {
        if (primzahl % zahl != 0) { istPrimzahl(primzahl, zahl + 1); }
        if (primzahl == zahl) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: First thing to note: any time you're calling `istPrimzahl` and not using the result, that's a bug...

Comment: You want to find all prime numbers in the universe this will not happen. Where is the end of your recursion ?

Comment: Usually, when a recursive function calls itself, it passes a new parameter value to the child call instead of its own exact parameter value. Otherwise, how will the child call do anything the parent call didn't?

Comment: i want to go as far as i can

Comment: Maybe if you are using big numbers you need to avoid recursion or change your [stack size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513438/c-sharp-recursion-depth-how-deep-can-you-go)

Comment: What part of your code you think prevents it from running infinitely?

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976333/stack-overflow-caused-by-recursive-function and get rid of the recursive function call. The language is different but the principle is the  same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing in your recursive code that will ultimately end the recursion:

```
static void primzahlenRekursiv(int primzahl) 
{
    if (istPrimzahl(primzahl, 2)) { Console.Writeline(primzahl); }
    primzahlenRekursiv(primzahl + 1);
}
```

`primzahlenRekursiv` always calls itself without any condition to stop it. Since any method call needs space on the stack, your algorithm will run until your stack runs out. Hence your exception.

In fact there is no need to run your algorthim recursively:

```
for (var kandidat = 2; ; kandidat++) {
    if (istPrimzahl(kandidat, 2)) { Console.Writeline(kandidat); }
}
```

This will run your code in an endless loop and not use up your stack *that quickly*. But be careful, eventually you will *still* run into a stack overflow exception if your candidate is getting high enough (you are still running recursion in `istPrimzahl`), just later. Therefore you better constrain your number set (in this example to 10000):

```
for (var kandidat = 2; kandidat < 10000; kandidat++) {
    if (istPrimzahl(kandidat, 2)) { Console.Writeline(kandidat); }
}
```

Also, in your code your recursion is not running correctly because of another error:

```
if (primzahl % zahl != 0) { istPrimzahl(primzahl, zahl + 1); }
```

...does not use the result of the recursive call. You are probably meaning to return the result of the recursive call at this spot.

Another solution would of course be a tail call, but C# doesn't support that (althogh IL would).

Comment: "Since any method call needs space on the stack" excluding [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

Comment: Yeah, I know. But we're in C# and in this context my claim still holds true, since there is no tail call there.

Comment: C#/.NET has tail calls

Comment: @PawełŁukasik: .NET yes, C# not.