# Recursive function to check if two matrices are equal using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I have written this program to check if two matrices are equal or not. Whenever I run it, it gives me **segmentation faults**.

```
int equal(int** matrix1, int** matrix2, int row, int col) {
    if(col < 0) {
        col = row;
        row--;
    }
    if(row < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(matrix1[row][col] == matrix2[row][col]) {
        return equal(matrix1, matrix2, row, col-1);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {

    int **ptr1 = new int*[3];
    int **ptr2 = new int*[3];
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        ptr1[i] = new int[3];
        ptr2[i] = new int[3];
    }

    ptr1[0][0] = 1;
    ptr1[0][1] = 2;
    ptr1[0][2] = 2;
    ptr1[1][0] = 4;
    ptr1[1][1] = 5;
    ptr1[1][2] = 6;
    ptr1[2][0] = 7;
    ptr1[2][1] = 8;
    ptr1[2][2] = 9;

    ptr2[0][0] = 1;
    ptr2[0][1] = 2;
    ptr2[0][2] = 2;
    ptr2[1][0] = 4;
    ptr2[1][1] = 5;
    ptr2[1][2] = 6;
    ptr2[2][0] = 7;
    ptr2[2][1] = 8;
    ptr2[2][2] = 9;

    cout << equal(ptr1, ptr2, 3, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to know that for array or pointers, `p[i]` is equal to `*(p + i)`. So why don't you use the much easier to read and understand array-indexing syntax in your function? So you do e.g. `matrix1[row][col]` instead?

Comment: You should not use `new`/`delete` manually in c++.  Also seems that a fix sized array would suffice for your case.

Comment: Aside boundary issue. The logic never checks for all of the elements. It only checks for `[3][3]` to `[3][0]` and `[3][0]` to `[0][0]`.

Comment: You're passing the number of elements to the function, but the function wants the indices of an element.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial call of the `equal` function is

```
equal(ptr1,ptr2,3,3)
```

That passes the *size* of the matrix as the `row` and `col` arguments, not the top indexes which is what the function expects.

That means when you do e.g. `matrix1[row][col]` you will go *out of bounds* and have *undefined behavior*.

Either change your logic in the function to always subtract one from the `row` and `col` values. Or (much simpler) change the initial call to use the top *index* instead of the size:

```
equal(ptr1,ptr2,2,2)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your time, my code is running great

Comment: @MuhammadHani I wouldn't use recursion the the first place unless it's or experimenting in an academic context or for fun.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code:

1. You pass the lenghts of matrix to `equal()` while using them as index in the function. Apparently `matrix[3][3]` cause out of bound access.
2. Compare logic only change `row` and `col` without checking every elements. You checked only 5 elements instead of all of them.
3. Use recursive approach when logic is easier to handle and the use cases don't get your [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15976333/4123703). However this case would be easier to read if you use iteration approach.

Assume inputs are correct (`col = 2` and `row = 2`).
Shows as below, where `[O]` is checked but `[X]` isn't.

```
   3  2  1
  [O][O][O]  // 1. [2][2]
4 [O][X][X]  // 2. [2][1]
5 [O][X][X]  // 3. [2][0]
             // 4. [1][0]
             // 5. [0][0]
```

The easiest way to compare a matrix should be using `std::vector` or `std::array`.
[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f5KnnTWsz)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int,3>, 3> m1{{{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}};
    std::array<std::array<int,3>, 3> m2{{{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}};
    std::array<std::array<int,3>, 3> m3{{{3,3,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}};
    std::cout << "m1 m2 compare result:" << std::boolalpha << (m1 == m2) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "m2 m3 compare result:" << std::boolalpha << (m3 == m2) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```